# Terraform Docker Provider: "Bind" port to specific network

Tags: docker, terraform-provider-docker

Launching a Docker Container that supports three networks:  Default Bridge(OAM), Bridge(Data In), & MacVLAN(Data Out).  The problem is that the Docker Provider seems to setup all the defined ports on the Default Bridge.  How do I tell Terraform to bind the defined ports to a specific Docker Network??

The .tf file snippit:

```
ports {
  # Data-In (Bridge)
  internal = 881
  external = 881
}
ports {
  # SSH Access on Default Bridge
  internal = 22
  external = 222
}
networks_advanced {
  name = "bridge"
}
networks_advanced {
  name = "data-in-net"
}
networks_advanced {
  name = "data-out-net"
}
```

The Docker networks:

```
# docker network list
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
1c2441b0b530        bridge              bridge              local
c68892f0c6e5        host                host                local
bb45d9dcbad1        none                null                local
a318d3bf3075        data-out-net        macvlan             local
af806334c7bf        data-in-net         bridge              local
```

Port 222 works, port 881 does not.

IPTables from the host OS running Docker:

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.32.2         tcp dpt:601
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.32.2         udp dpt:syslog
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:881
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:ssh
```

The `tcp dpt:881` line needs to have a destination of `192.168.32.3`.  The syslog container ONLY uses the Data-In Docker Network, and thus has a correct IP address.

Any sugggestions/workarounds??  Thanks! :)

Comment: The ports settings are for connections from outside Docker space into the container; they're not associated with any of the Docker networking modes or internal networks (except that they're ignored if you select host networking). It'd be a little unusual for a container to be on multiple networks, but only listen to some of them; can you provide a more complete [mcve] describing the image you're trying to run, and where these IP addresses come from?

Comment: @DavidMaze: I added a bit more detail, but any container that has open ports on more than one Docker Network will show this issue.  The IP address are auto-assigned from Docker...its how it works ;)